# How can I create and save a file under PARI/GP?

Tags: io, pari

This is the first time I'm working with PARI/GP under Windows. I have to create a file and save it to write my code.

I tried the \r and \w and didn't work. I couldn't also find much documentation. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can read with `read`, `readstr`, `readvec`, `fileread`, and `filereadstr`. Try typing `?read`, for example, to see the quick help entry for that command.

Likewise, you can write with `write`, `write1`, `writebin`, `writetex`, `filewrite`, and `filewrite1`.